# Master/detail form in Axapta/Dynamics Ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

How do I create a master/detail form in Axapta/Dynamics Ax, with a master grid and a detail grid, where choosing a record in the master grid changes the content of the detail grid accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://daxdave.blogspot.com/2006/10/creating-headerdetail-based-linkage-on.html

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit to James' answer, often you can find an example of what your trying to do just by looking at an existing form.  You didn't specify whether you were working in Dynamics AX 2012 or an earlier version, but you'd probably want to build a ListPage and Detail form if it's 2012.  For an example, take a look at the EcoResProductListPage and EcoResProductDetails forms and see how they connect.